# How to make the default property something other than Content in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm new to Windows app development. I'm creating a custom `UserControl` which other users will be able to use in their apps. I want to configure my control such that if you put anything inside of it, it will assign to a property other than `Content`. To give you a better explanation, if you write this:

```
<Button>Hello, world!</Button>
```

It would be equivalent to as if you had written this:

```
<Button Content="Hello, world!"/>
```

Can I make the XAML parser set the contents for my control to a property other than `Content`, or is this not possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ContentPropertyAttribute:

```
[ContentProperty("DefaultProperty")]
```

More at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx

Comment: Awesome, wouldn't have guessed it could be this easy. Thanks!